# How can I quickly check Drupal 7 porting status of the contributed projects?

Tags: 7, migrations, updating

How can I quickly check Drupal 7 porting status of the contributed projects ?

Answers should also guide readers if

- a user is a *developer* and would like to help porting the most
  frequently needed Drupal contributed modules, or
- a user is a *website owner*
  and would like to assess a possible upgrade from Drupal 6
  to Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [Drupal 7 contributed project porting status](https://drupal.org/sandbox/webchick/1223824) website that uses data from the Upgrade Status module to show Drupal 7 porting status of the top 61 contributed projects.